# Why does fundamental matrix have 7 degrees of freedom?

Tags: image-processing, camera, computer-vision

There are 9 parameters in the fundamental matrix to relate the pixel co-ordinates of left and right images but only 7 degrees of freedom (DOF).

The reasoning for this on several pages that I've searched says :

1. Homogenous equations means we lose a degree of freedom
2. The determinant of F = 0, therefore we lose another degree of freedom.

I don't understand why those 2 reasons mean we lose 2 DOF - can someone explain it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

We initially have 9 DOF because the fundamental matrix is composed of 9 parameters, which implies that we need 9 corresponding points to compute the fundamental matrix (F). Because of the following two reasons, we only need 7 corresponding points.

#### Reason 1

We lose 1 DOF because we are using **homogeneous coordinates**. This basically is a way to represent nD points as a vector form by adding an extra dimension. ie) A 2D point (0,2) can be represented as [0,2,1], in general [x,y,1]. There are useful properties when using homogeneous coordinates with 2D/3D transformation, but I'm going to assume you know that.

Now given the expression p and p' representing pixel coordinates:

```
p'=[u',v',1] and p=[u,v,1]
```

the fundamental matrix:

```
F = [f1,f2,f3]
    [f4,f5,f6]
    [f7,f8,f9]
```

and fundamental matrix equation:

```
(transposed p')Fp = 0
```

when we multiply this expression in algebra form, we get the following:

```
uu'f1 + vu'f2 + u'f3 + uv'f4 + vv'f5 + v'f6 + uf7 + vf8 + f9 = 0.
```

In a homogeneous system of linear equation form Af=0 (basically the factorization of the above formula), we get two components A and f.

A:

```
[uu',vu',u', uv',vv',v',u,v,1]
```

f (f is essentially the fundamental matrix in vector form):

```
[f1,f2'f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9]
```

Now if we look at the components of vector A, we have 8 unknowns, but value of one of terms is already known (1 in this case) because of homogeneous coordinates. Thus we need only 8 equations now.

#### Reason 2

```
det F = 0.
```

A determinant is a value that can be obtained from a square matrix.

I'm not entirely sure about the mathematical details of this property but I can still infer the basic idea, and, hopefully, you can as well.

Basically given some matrix A

```
A = [a,b,c]
    [d,e,f]
    [g,h,i]
```

The determinant can be computed using this formula:

```
det A = aei+bfg+cdh-ceg-bdi-afh
```

If we look at the determinant using the fundamental matrix, the algebra would look something like this:

```
F = [f1,f2,f3]
    [f4,f5,f6]
    [f7,f8,f9]

det F = (f1*f5*f8)+(f2*f6*f7)+(f3*f4*f8)-(f3*f5*f7)-(f2*f4*f9)-(f1*f6*f8)
```

Now we know the determinant of the fundamental matrix is zero:

```
det F = (f1*f5*f8)+(f2*f6*f7)+(f3*f4*f8)-(f3*f5*f7)-(f2*f4*f9)-(f1*f6*f8) = 0
```

So, if we work out only 7 of the 9 parameters of the fundamental matrix, we can work out the last parameter using the above determinant equation.

Therefore the fundamental matrix has 7DOF.

Comment: This is the best explanation I can found so far. But I am struggling on 5 DOF of the essential matrix. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: BTW, if "the mathematical details of this property" means det(F) = 0. My understanding is the skew-symmetric matrix in F has rank 2 and the property of matrix multiplication is rank(AB) <= min(rank(A), rank(B)). Then F must have equal or less than rank 2, so det(F) = 0

Comment: Simply the essential matrix (E) is the fundamental matrix taking into account the camera intrinsic parameters. Now the formula is (transposed p')Ep = 0 where we try to solve E. E matrix can be decomposed and solved for rotation (R), and translation (t) component for p' to match p which are the 5DOF. In typical 3D geometry transformations, we have 9DOF (translation, rotation, scale). But in this case we have 5DOF because with the essential matrix, we are working in a normalized coordinate system, and therefore the scale becomes ambiguous (down 6DOF now).

Comment: We also lose another 5DOF from one of the translational axis (not too sure but basically one of the rotations or translations just doesn't change the final E computed). I simply read remember it as "basically knowning camera intrinsic parameters reduce the number of points needed to solve E (not necessarily the mathematics though)." What once used to be a linear problem with the 7-point algorithm becomes a non-linear problem with the 5-point algorithm. Maybe their paper might give you more detail.

Comment: Great explanation! If F has only 7 DOTs, don't we just need 4 corresponding feature points (4 matched feature point pairs) for F? Because each corresponding feature point pair provide 2 linear independent equations?

Answer (score 8):

The reasons why F has only 7 degrees of freedom are

1. F is a 3x3 homogeneous matrix. Homogeneous means there is a scale ambiguity in the matrix, so the scale doesn't matter (as shown in @Curator Corpus 's example). This drops one degree of freedom.
2. F is a matrix with rank 2. It is not a full rank matrix, so it is singular and its determinant is zero (Proof [here](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/VectorLessons/vmch16/vmch16_15.html)). The reason why F is a matrix with rank 2 is that it is mapping a 2D plane (image1) to all the lines (in image 2) that pass through the epipole (of image 2).

Hope it helps.

Comment: How does this explain that F has 7 degrees of freedom? Sure, it's clear that F is scale-invariant, so there are at most 8 degrees of freedom, but how does having rank 2 decreases the degrees of freedom?

Comment: Good question. Here is how the logic flows.

Comment: 1. F has a matrix with rank 2.
2. Then its determinant is zero.
3. @Curator Corpus has shown that det F = (f1*f5*f8)+(f2*f6*f7)+(f3*f4*f8)-(f3*f5*f7)-(f2*f4*f9)-(f1*f6*f8) = 0. So for any two unknown variables, say f9 and f8, we can establish an equation that f9 = a * f8 + b where a, b are coefficients determined by the rest of the variables (f1 - f7). Note that f9 also satisfies the equation of c + d *f8 = f9 as explained in Curator's reason 1 (where c, d are also coefficients of f1-f7). Combined with two equations together, both f9 and f8 are determined. 

Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

As for the highest votes answer by nbro, I think it can be interpreted as this way where we have reason two, matrix `F` has a rank2, so its determinant is zero as a constraint to the `f` variable function. So, we only need 7 points to determine the rest of variables (f1-f8), with the previous constriant. And 8 equations, 8 variables, leaving only one solution. So there is 7 DOF.